# How to make a Realm collection observer section aware like `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, realm, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I’m new to Realm and I’m hoping it can do something that is easy in CoreData. First, I’m going to explain how it works with CoreData, then I’ll ask if or how it can be accomplished with Realm.

TL;DR: I’m hoping Realm has functionality similar to what you get with `NSFetchedResultsController`, specifically how it effortlessly manages table view sections.  If you know the answer you can probably skip the details below.

Here’s the scenario. Let’s say we have a data model like this:

```
￼┌────────────────┐
│Category        │
│ - name         │             ┌────────────────┐
│ - description  │┼─────┐      │Item            │
│ - items        │      │     ┌│ - name         │
│ - dateCreated  │      └────○┼│ - description  │
└────────────────┘            └│ - category     │
                               │ - dateCreated  │
                               └────────────────┘
```

A `Category` can have many `Items`. An `Item` has one `Category`.

And let’s say we’re displaying some `Item`s in a table view. The table view is sectioned by `Category`. So it looks like this:

```
￼┌──────────────┐
│Camping       │
│ Axe          │
│ Firestartor  │
│Clothing      │
│ Bug shirt    │
│ Long pants   │
│              │
└──────────────┘
```

Yes, there’s a typo. We’ll get to that. Camping is a `Category` and is displayed in a section header. Its `Item`s are the rows in that section. Same with Clothing, it’s a `Category` and it’s in the section header and its `Item`s are the rows in that section.

With CoreData this is easy to accomplish with an `NSFetchedResultsController` like this:

```
let fr = NSFetchRequest<Item> = NSFetchRequest(…)
fr.predicate = …
fr.sortDescriptors = …
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fr, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: “category.name”, cacheName: nil)
```

The fetch request, `fr`, is a lot like a Realm query. It specifies the entity along with a predicate and sort descriptors. In this case assume the sort descriptors are saying to sort by the item name within the category name.

But for sections, the key is providing a value for the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter. The value is relative to the entity you specify in the fetch request. So in this case `category.name` is relative to `Item`. `Item` has a `Category` and a `Category` has a name. So the sections are going to be `Category` names.

Now, in `cellForRowAt` I just do this

```
let item = frc.object(at: indexPath)
cell.textField.text = item.name
```

Since we provided the `sectionNameKeyPath`, the fetched results controller has already done all the work and has sorted out the sections and knows which `Item`s are in what sections. That’s all there is to loading a sectioned table view with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Furthermore, like a Realm collection observer, `NSFetchedResultsController` listens for changes. In this case it’s listening for changes to `Item`s. Let’s say the user taps another tab on the tab bar and goes someplace else in the app, notices that typo for "firestartor" and fixes it. The `frc` back on the other view controller will notice that change and call its delegate method, where it hands me the indexPath for that row, and I can just update the cell. I don’t need to do any kind of processing to figure out the index path, it simply hands me the correct index path.

Questions:

1. Does Realm have a mechanism like `NSFetchedResultsController` that makes working with sections easy or is the section lovin’ entirely up to the developer?

The docs for RealmCollectionChange say...

> The change information is available in two formats: a simple array of row indices in the collection for each type of change, and an array of index paths in a requested section suitable for passing directly to UITableView’s batch update methods.

2. All I'm getting is the simple array of row indices. How do you get the other format? The one with the array of index paths?

Comment: Not sure the question is super clear, and a good answer will be determined by how you create a section. For example, in your example, you have sections with A, B, C... and then user names are in the section that matches the letter. If a users last name changes from Smith to Jones then that object will be passed to the observer and you can remove it from the Smith section and insert it in the Jones section - that's one of the reasons the docs spell out the order; *In collection notification handlers, always apply changes in the following order: deletions, insertions, then modifications*.

Comment: @Jay In the case of changing Smith to Jones, the `RealmCollectionChange` object does not provide enough information. It is returning a simple array of row indices. I could, of course, just `reloadData()` but then there's no animation. I'm hoping there's a way to get the new indexPath.

Comment: @Jay I took your comment about not being super clear to heart and I have edited the question. Now I'm fully describing what can be accomplished in CoreData, then asking if Realm has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is how to handle discreet insert, delete's and modify using a Realm observer so then an animation can be applied in a tableView.

Let me address this kind of generically as we don't know how the tableView sections and rows are being populated.

Assume we have a bunch of Person objects stored in Realm with each Person having a name property. We load those persons into a tableView datasource and have an observer on those results. Here's the 'guts' to show how each object is accessed via their index

```
func observePeople() {
    self.peopleToken = self.peopleResults!.observe { changes in
            switch changes {
            case .initial(let people):
                print("  initial object load complete")
                for person in people {
                    print("\(person.name)")
                }

            case .update(let persons, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                for index in deletions {
                    let deletedPerson = persons[index]
                    print("  deletedAccount: \(deletedPerson.name)")
                }

                for index in insertions {
                    let insertedPerson = persons[index]
                    print("  insertedAccount: \(insertedPerson.name)")
                }

                for index in modifications {
                    let modifiedPerson = persons[index]
                    print("  modifiedAccount: \(modifiedPerson.name)")
                }

            case .error(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
}
```

Suppose a user modifies their last name from Jones to Smith. This section of the observe code will execute

```
for index in modifications {
   let modifiedPerson = persons[index]
   print("  modifiedPerson: \(modifiedPerson.name)")
}
```

and this will print to the console

```
modifiedPerson: Smith
```

To add an animation to a tableView that has rows and sections, replace or augment the above code in the case statement with:

```
case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
     ... determine the section. for example, first char is A=0, B=1, C=2 etc
     tableView.beginUpdates()behavior.
     tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ getPath(for: $0) )}),
                          with: .automatic)
     tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ getPath(for: $0) }),
                          with: .automatic)
     tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ getPath(for: $0) }),
                          with: .automatic)
     tableView.endUpdates()
```

and then the function that determines where this object is in the dataSource and returns the index path to that object, supporting the animation.

```
func getPathFor(myPerson: PersonClass) {
   //determine which object this is in the array and return it's indexPath
   return indexPath
}
```

So for example, if we are using sections being A, B, C and the user Jones is the first person in section J, that would be section 9, row 0. e.g. let jones = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 9).

There are a number of other ways to do this process as well but this one works for us.

Comment: Perhaps not originally very clear (I apologize, but hopefully better now) I have 2 questions. Based on your code, I think you're saying that the answer to my first question is that there's nothing equivalent to `NSFetchedResultsController` and that we are responsible for table view section management. Is that correct? If so, your examples will be helpful. Thank you. That's the first question. Do you have the answer for question 2 regarding the other format for `RealmCollectionChange`?